# How to check user input and field from getters

Tags: java

I have problem, and dont know is this a IDE bug or something. I will display the code piece by piece and write what the result of the code is after running.

I have this method:

```
 public void chooseFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
    System.out.println("Choose flight by ID: ");
    int pickedFlight = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    for (Flight tempFlight : flightList) {
        if (pickedFlight == tempFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You picked flight from: " + tempFlight.getFrom() + ", to "
                    + tempFlight.getTo() + ". Prices are: | Economic class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass() + " | Business class : "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForBusinessClass() + " | First class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForFirstClass());
            selectedFlight = tempFlight;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID doesnt exist");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The user enters the ID and thus selects the flight, each flight has an ID, if the ID entered by the user matches the flight ID, the flight information is displayed, otherwise the flight does not exist, more precisely the ID entered by the user does not match with none of the flights.

This is how I save flights:

```
Flight flight1 = new Flight(1, "Moscow", "Belgrade", 300, 600, 850, "gC49");
    Flight flight2 = new Flight(2, "Paris", "Dortmund", 250, 290, 400, "soe4");
    Flight flight3 = new Flight(3, "Podgorica", "Nis", 25, 40, 80, "sx33");
    Flight flight4 = new Flight(4, "London", "Miami", 600, 1500, 2500, "zcl3");

ArrayList<Flight> flightsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    flightsArrayList.add(flight1);
    flightsArrayList.add(flight2);
    flightsArrayList.add(flight3);
    flightsArrayList.add(flight4);
```

Output after running first method above is If I enter any ID other than number 1

`Flight ID doesnt exist` although I entered an ID that matches the flight ID.

If I enter 1 program print me the corresponding flight, if I enter another flight ID the program displays a message that the flight does not exist although there is

But, If I delete this `else` statement from first method:

```
} else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID doesnt exist");
        }
        System.exit(0);
```

Program works fine, I just dont know where is my mistake.

Comment: you should not print that within the for loop, you should keep a boolean flag and based on that, print it after the loop

Comment: Thank you for help, but I really dont know how to implement that, im begginer

Comment: check the answer I posted, maybe that 'll make it more clear

Comment: if your question is answered, can you mark the question solved?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Flight tempFlight : flightList) {
        if (pickedFlight == tempFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You picked flight from: " + tempFlight.getFrom() + ", to "
                    + tempFlight.getTo() + ". Prices are: | Economic class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass() + " | Business class : "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForBusinessClass() + " | First class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForFirstClass());
            selectedFlight = tempFlight;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID doesnt exist");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Your problem seems a problem of scope:

For each element you check, you print that message if it's not found, and at the end of the loop, you call System.exit(0);, meaning, you only check the first element of the List.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Flight tempFlight : flightList) {
        if (pickedFlight == tempFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You picked flight from: " + tempFlight.getFrom() + ", to "
                    + tempFlight.getTo() + ". Prices are: | Economic class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass() + " | Business class : "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForBusinessClass() + " | First class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForFirstClass());
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    } // this ends the for loop

if ( found ) {
  // you actually found the Flight
} else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID doesnt exist");
        }
        System.exit(0);
```

EDIT: assuming you want to use the Flight and extract data from it after you've found it:

```
Flight found = null;
for (Flight tempFlight : flightList) {
        if (pickedFlight == tempFlight.getId()) {
            System.out.println("You picked flight from: " + tempFlight.getFrom() + ", to "
                    + tempFlight.getTo() + ". Prices are: | Economic class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass() + " | Business class : "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForBusinessClass() + " | First class: "
                    + tempFlight.getPriceForFirstClass());
            found = tempFlight;
            break;
        }
    } // this ends the for loop

if ( found != null ) {
  // you actually found the Flight
} else {
            System.out.println("Flight ID doesnt exist");
        }
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Program print me  the corresponding flight but immediately after that prints that the flight ID I entered does not exist

Comment: Also for this `if (found != null) im getting warning that `Condition 'found != null' is always 'false' `

Comment: @asu which is impossible. My guess, you forgot to add the "found = tempFlight;" line.
right after the object is printed, you assign that to found, so that can no longer be null. you get that message because you don't reassign found.

Comment: @asu have you retried after my remark? do you still have problems?